Accessing 'self.user' or 'self.user_id' in Django model's clean() method
I need to know if this is possible in a model's clean or save method (ideally clean), without using forms, as I want specific validation logic to be directly tied to the model so that both forms and manager commands (e.g., Model.objects.create() in shell or views) are validated equally.
Example:
I have ModelB where user is a foreign key of ModelA:
class ModelB(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

ModelB has a form:
class ModelBForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ('some_field')

    some_field = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)

I have a get view in a CBV where a form is instantiated for the logged-in user:
form = ModelBForm(user=request.user)
In the post view under the CBV, the form for ModelB is validated before ModelB is created:
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()

As we all know, form.is_valid() calls model.clean() via self.instance.full_clean(). , and I'm looking to validate something about self.user under the clean() method of ModelB like so:
class ModelB(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    
    def clean(self):
        if self.user.id == 1:                    # Example validation 
           raise ValidationError('blahblahblah')
         

However, in this Model B clean method, self.user produces:
raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(
models.ModelB.user.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: ModelB has no user.

and self.user_id returns None.

Essentially, is it possible to reference self.user or self.user_id in ModelB's clean method, or must it go in its save method?

Please provide a proper [mre] so that we can reproduce your issue. In this case the error simply points out that you haven't specified any user attribute for the model object. I am guessing you're adding some logic to automatically set the user from the request.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Updated. The information provided should suffice to create a proper minimal reproducible example.

Duplicate of: Django, adding excluded properties to the submitted modelform (Update self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None) to self.instance.user = kwargs.pop('user', None) or write form.instance.user = request.user in the view)
